# Java Slow Searching in ANC (big file)

Tags: java, search, bigdata

I'm using the American National Corpus to get the frequency of a word in English.
The file structure is the following (it's a big file, ~8 MB):

```
Word1   Lemma1  Pos1    Frequency1
Word2   Lemma2  Pos2    Frequency2
Word3   Lemma3  Pos3    Frequency3
```

Here is my Java Class, but it's extremely slow... how can I change it to speed it up?
(I want to find the Frequency related to a specific word)

```
    public static int frequency (String word) throws Exception {

    int ft=0;
    int fc=0;
    int exit=0;
    String frow;
    String[] separated = new String[10];
    String fwordC = "...";
    String fwordP = "...";

    Scanner fscan = new Scanner(new File("./ANC-all-lemma.data"));
    fscan.useDelimiter("\n");

    while(fscan.hasNext()){
        frow = fscan.next();
        separated = frow.split("    ");

        separated[0]= separated[0].replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "");
        fwordC = separated[0]; //set current word

        if (fwordC.equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
            System.out.println("Found!!!");
            return(separated[3]);
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Why not load that file to a hive table or pig relation and do a query? 
Apache Hive (http://hive.apache.org/)
Apache Pig (http://pig.apache.org/)

Comment: do you any thing about [threads](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616109/Java-Thread-Tutorial)? you need to separate your big work into [small ones](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616115/Java-Thread-Example#ai), in fact run thread for each line

Comment: 8 MB is s tiny file these days even for a phone.  You can read each line and only split the ones which start with the string you want.  It would be much faster if you store the data in memory and look up a Map.  Looking up a Map take less than a micro-second.

Comment: @ArunAK A database for an 8 MB file?

Comment: @Peter : That solution was for Large Files/ Huge files. Not specific for 8Mb.
There would be enough number of lines apt for firing a query in a local mode for pig. That definitely would solve the requirement without much lines of coding.

Comment: @ArunAK Even 8 GB I would load it into memory, it could still be faster than using a database.  8 TB; you definitely want a database.

Comment: I don't call Pig a database. More over running a pig query in local mode for this tiny file would not bring in any overhead.

Comment: (I used the @Peter soggestion: the map works really well!)

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely try reading with [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html). Scanner is used to parse data. BufferedReader also has a larger buffer of around 8 KB.